# what is wrong with this code, I am using PHP 8

Tags: php, dom

The loop never stop, also it always print, not only when $i is equal 8

```
$file  = file_get_contents ($fileUrl);
$i = 0;
        
while ($line = explode ("\r\n", $file)) {
            
    if ($i == 8) {
        print_r ($line);
        exit ();
    }
            
    $i++;
}
```

By the way, I need to use file_get_contents because I am using DOM, but I use that code because I need the data in line number 8, is there any better way to get a specific line

Comment: What sort of content are you reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is infinite because `explode` always explodes the entire file string and it never fails.  You can read it into an array, but this is only useful without the `exit` if you are doing things with other lines in the file:

```
foreach(file($fileUrl) as $line) {
    if ($i == 8) {  // actually the ninth line
        print_r ($line);
    }                
    $i++;
}
```

Or read it as you are and get the proper line:

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $file);
print_r($lines[8]);  // actually the ninth line
```

Comment: I hate while loop lol, I am never learned to used correctly, thank you

Comment: you are crack, the second code is the best

Answer (score 0):

You're not looping through the lines. You're setting `$line` to an array of all the lines, not a specific line. And you're setting it to the same thing every time through the loop, so the `while` condition will never change.

However, the loop should stop when `$i == 8` because of the `exit()` call. It will then print all the lines with `print_r()`.

If you want line `8`, just index the array.

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $file);
if (count($lines) >= 9) {
    print_r($lines[8]);
}
```

FYI, you can also use `file()` to read a file and split it into lines:

```
$lines = file($fileUrl, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now what I am doing wrong, thank god I do not live from coding or I'll be already dead

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the 8th line, you can simply do this:

```
$line = explode ("\r\n", $file)[8];
print_r($line);
```

without using a loop

and regarding you question for infinite loop

```
$line = explode ("\r\n", $file)
```

returns a true, since you are just assigning an array to this variable.
you should use `foreach` here like this:

```
    foreach(explode ("\r\n", $file) as $line){
 // TO DO
    }
```